# Moderator nominations

Tags: discussion, moderators

According to [this post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/), three temp moderators will be selected in about 2 weeks. Who would like to nominate themselves?

Answer (score 6):

I am nominating myself, also (and I also support marcog's nomination).

- I have a great interest in the [policy aspects](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/policy) of this site, as can be seen by my meta posts.
- I'm one of the [earliest users](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13) on SO<sup>†</sup>, so I've seen a lot as far as how a Stack Exchange site's culture evolves.
- I've run [the third-most popular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62188) code golf (by number of upvotes) on SO. :-P

Clearly, I'm invested in code golf. I also have interest in other code challenges (and I plan to post some soon), so, I'm not playing favourites here. If you love coding brain-twisters, I look forward to helping you twist your brain as much as it can handle! :-)

† This by itself required some creativity<sup>‡</sup> (as did my getting userid 3 on this site), so I see this as a sign of my interest in solving outside-the-square problems. :-)

‡ Ask me if you're curious. :-P

Comment: +1 You've been very active on meta.

Comment: I second your nomination.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to nominate myself. I am a 14k SO user so I have experience with SE sites, and while this is my first involvement in a beta site I have a great interest in making it work out. I am one of the top users on [the `[algorithm]` tag on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/algorithm/topusers), which I feel is very related to this site's purpose. Although this is early stages, I have already posted 9 of the 20 questions on meta and 7 meta answers. I have posted a [couple](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/31/methods-of-counting-characters-on-various-systems) [experimental](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) questions on the main site. I also currently have the [highest rep](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users), although it's far too early for this to be meaningful.

Comment: You also seem to want to penalize people for doing nothing wrong: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25/code-golf-answers-that-arent-golfing-attempts - I vote no.

Comment: @Noah Please read my reply to your comment there. That question clearly opened up an issue we're currently facing. I have no intention of penalising people for doing nothing wrong, but I do have see the need to discuss what is necessary.

Comment: I second @marcog's nomination.

Comment: I second your nomination.